# How to align two divs next to each other, first is fixed width, second is dynamic height

Tags: css

I am trying to produce responsive css for the following scenario.  We have a div container (henceforth called 'the parent div/container').  Inside that div is an icon (represented by the 'X's below) and a set of text inside a div next to it (represented by the 'Y's below).  Both 'X' and 'Y' containers have borders.  The icon is 44px wide and we want the 'Y' container to be 100% of the remaining width.   If the screen is resized, the 'Y' container flexes, taking up (or removing) additional lines as necessary. If the text is too long to fit on one line it will wrap within its own container.  Roughly like this:

```
_____  ____________________
|XXXX| |YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY| <-Edge of screen
|XXXX| |YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY|
------ |YYYYYYYY           |
       --------------------
```

We've tried this a number of ways, but I've not been happy with any. My current attempt (somewhat simplified):

```
#parent { position:relative; }
#X { width: 44px; border: 1px solid red;}
#Y { position: absolute: left: 44px; top: 0px; border: 1px solid red }
```

This work for a number of my requirements, except that if the text overflows onto multiple lines the height of the 'Y' container is greater than the parent container and overlaps further content below the parent container.  It also does not fill the remaining width.

I'd like to find a more elegant css-only solution to this.  Any help appreciated!

EDIT: HTML looks like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='X'><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></div>
    <div id='Y'>text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the code that you have for your `HTML`?

Comment: @demogorgon.net - HTML now added.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `display: flex` as shown below. It allows you to have exactly what you needed without taking too much care about the child elements.

```css
#parent {
  /* Set parent to flex, starting at
     the very left corner. */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* If you want the icon to be on top,
     use flex-start instead of center */
  align-items: center;
}

#X {
  /* Set fixed width. This part is important,
     otherwise it would stretch the icon */
  width: 44px;
}

#Y {
  /* Set the #Y container to 100% width.
     It will be stretched since it is a
     relative width but its content stays within its borders */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="X"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></div>
    <div id="Y">text goes here<br>
      with some more<br>lines</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @lumio, this also seems to work well.  It feels more intuitive as well.